# The property name of the controller does not match the one specified by bake (CakePHP4)

Tags: cakephp, properties, controller, cake-bake

i have created a table named "foo_logs" by bake migrations.
and then, created model and controller named "FooLogs" by bake.

Now, the model and controller have been created. The controller has a property called "$FooLogs" (bake wrote).

i tried to get the data for "foo_logs" but I see "Call to a member function find () on null".
as follows;

```
$fooLogs = $this->paginate($this->FooLogs->find('all')->where($conditions));
```

i searched for the reason why $ this-> FooLogs is null. then, when identifying the modelClass, i confirmed that "Foologs" was used (l instead of L).

i want to know why "Foologs" is used. bakes it was completed as "FooLogs"!
maybe the word "log" has a special meaning in CakePHP?

thanks in advance.
reguards,

Comment: `$this->Foologs->find('all')->where($conditions)` is _not_ [**code created by bake**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/2.3.0/templates/bake/element/Controller/index.twig#L29).

Comment: yes, you are right. that is changes by me for my works.

Comment: bake wrotes `$fooLogs = $this->paginate($this->FooLogs);`.  The problem is not it, why the property "FooLogs" is internally "Foologs".  regards,

Comment: btw, `$this->paginate($this->FooLogs)` does not raise an exception.  in this case, $this->FooLogs is null and the model identification is done by the "FooLogs" derived from the controller name.

Comment: i think "FooLogs" is the correct property name. in a hurry, i wrote `$this->loadModel('FooLogs')` in initialize () to initialize the properties.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is the link output to the page of the controller, as follows. It was because the controller name was "foologs" as follows:

`$this->Html->link('xxxxx', ['controller' => 'foologs'])`

When resolving a model class, only the first letter seems to be capitalized (foologs → Foologs).

It's an ordinary mistake. I confirmed that it works without any problem by writing the controller name correctly.

I apologize to you for a fuss over.